# Boostrap thumbnail slider load dynamic conent

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I have a thumbnail slider on index page

```
<div class="productslider carousel slide data-slider" id="prod158">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <ul>
                <li class="product col-sm-2">
                    <a href="#" alt="">
                        <img src="#" width="160" height="120" alt="loading">
                        <span>Title</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="text">Price</span>
                </li>
            </ul>                            
        </div>

        <a data-slide="prev" href="#prod158" class="left carousel-control">
            <span class="prev_btn"></span>
        </a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#prod158" class="right carousel-control"> 
            <span class="next_btn"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

So how do I load dynamic data on this slider (where & how i pleased foreach loop).

Note :

1. This is a laravel project.if you use blade syntax,then i will more helpful.
2. li should be looped five times.
3. if there is 10 products then item class should be looped 2 times.

Data Source : `Product::all();`

Comment: pleased a foreach loop at the top of the li element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="productslider carousel slide data-slider" id="prod158">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
       @foreach(array_chunk($products,5) as $row)
        <div class="item active">
                <ul>
                @foreach($row as $product)
                  <li class="product col-sm-2">
                      <a href="#" alt="">
                          <img src="#" width="160" height="120" alt="loading">
                          <span>Title</span>
                       </a>
                     <span class="text">Price</span>
                   </li>
                 @endforeach
                 </ul>                            
               </div>
      @endforeach
     <a data-slide="prev" href="#prod158" class="left carousel-control">
         <span class="prev_btn"></span></a>
     <a data-slide="next" href="#prod158" class="right carousel-control"> 
         <span class="next_btn"></span></a>
```